# Fill in missing numbers in different lists twice. ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: vb.net

I need your help to prepare data. I am reading a byte array. I make bytes to unsigned integers. I read in different blocks of that array and write the `UInt32s` in 5 lists in total. The data has been stored compressed; that is, some spaces are missing and I need to fill them up. To make it clear, I made a compilable test project for you and wrote the data into an excel file.

**This is the original data.**  
 **From the left to the right: Sizes, Addresses, Indexes, Number_of_items, Description** 
[image: This is the original file.]  
You can see that in column C the 2, 3, and 4 are missing. So I select columns C through E, and move them down 3 rows. I fill the gaps with 2, 3, 4 in column C and 1, 1, 1 in the other two columns.
[image]  
I do this until I reach the end of column B. Columns B, C, D, and E must have the same length.
[image]

#### Where I have a little problem

I fail because a While or For loop evaluates the List.Count property only once. That is, if I add something to a list within the loop, the loop doesn't run often enough. I've provisionally worked around this by writing `While True` and catching an OutOfRangeException. Maybe someone has a better idea; or even an idea that completely replaces my approach :D

### Step № 2

If a row has a 2 in column D, I select columns B through E below the 2, and move the contents down one row (only one, because the difference is 1).
[image]  
    
I want to do this until I get to the bottom of the table. This will make all columns the same length.
[image]  
Again, I have the problem that I use `While True` and go out using an exception. Does anyone have a better idea?

**FormMain.vb**

```
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private Sizes As New List(Of UInt32) From {
        58_355UI,
20_270UI,
4_830UI,
4_443UI,
25_177UI,
8_844UI,
4_101UI,
4_200UI,
14_991UI,
12_639UI,
12_894UI,
14_165UI,
12_954UI,
26_670UI,
7_388UI}

    Private Addresses As New List(Of UInt32) From {4_323UI, 62_706UI, 83_646UI, 88_935UI, 93_883UI, 128_259UI, 132_718UI,
        137_254UI, 152_590UI, 178_485UI, 193_022UI, 206_718UI}

    Private Indexes As New List(Of UInt32) From {1UI, 5UI, 6UI, 9UI, 10UI, 12UI}

    Private NumberOfItems As New List(Of UInt32) From {1UI, 2UI, 1UI, 2UI, 1UI, 2UI}
    Private Description As New List(Of UInt32) From {1UI, 1UI, 1UI, 1UI, 1UI, 1UI}
    Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
        Dim RopD As New Reprocessing_of_parsed_data(Sizes, Addresses, Indexes, NumberOfItems, Description)
        RopD.Fill_gaps()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Reprocessing_of_parsed_data.vb**

```
Public NotInheritable Class Reprocessing_of_parsed_data
    Public Property Sizes As New List(Of UInteger)
    Public Property Addresses As New List(Of UInteger)
    Public Property Indexes As New List(Of UInteger)
    Public Property Number_of_items As New List(Of UInteger)
    Public Property Description As New List(Of UInteger)

    Public Sub New(sizes As List(Of UInt32), addresses As List(Of UInt32), indexes As List(Of UInt32), number_of_items As List(Of UInt32), description As List(Of UInt32))
        Me.Sizes = sizes
        Me.Addresses = addresses
        Me.Indexes = indexes
        Me.Number_of_items = number_of_items
        Me.Description = description
    End Sub

    Public Sub Fill_gaps()
        Dim counterForAddressesList As Integer = 0
        'Dim ListCount As Integer = Indexes.Count - 2
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While True 'i < ListCount - 2
            Try
                Dim delta As Integer = CInt(Indexes(i + 1) - Indexes(i)) - 1
                Dim number As UInt32 = Indexes(i)
                While delta > 0
                    number += 1UI
                    counterForAddressesList += 1
                    Indexes.Insert(CInt(number) - 1, number)
                    Number_of_items.Insert(CInt(number) - 1, 1UI)
                    Description.Insert(CInt(number) - 1, 1UI)
                    delta -= 1
                    'ListCount += 1
                End While
                counterForAddressesList += 1
                i += 1
            Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                Exit While
            End Try
        End While

        ' Step 2

        Dim j As Integer = 0
        While True
            Try
                If Number_of_items(j) > 1UI Then
                    Dim delta As Integer = CInt(Number_of_items(j)) - 1
                    While delta > 0
                        Addresses.Insert(j + 1, UInteger.MaxValue)
                        Indexes.Insert(j + 1, UInteger.MaxValue)
                        Number_of_items.Insert(j + 1, UInteger.MaxValue)
                        Description.Insert(j + 1, UInteger.MaxValue)
                        delta -= 1
                        j += 1
                    End While
                End If
                j += 1
            Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                Exit While
            End Try
        End While

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When I want to process a list or dictionary that affects the number of items, I process the list in reverse or use keys in array. "For Each o In MyDictionary.Values.Reverse" or "For Each o In MyDictionary.Keys.Reverse" or "For Each o In MyDictionary.Keys.ToArray" Now you can add items without exceptions.

Comment: In your example code you have 12 indexes. 3 rows have 2 NumberOfItems. I.e., after step no. 2 you will have 15 rows, but you have only 12 Sizes. Shouldn't there be 15 sizes for column A?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You are right. Damn, I wrote 3 Sizes too few in the initialization of the list. **Edit:** I added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never a good idea to catch an index out of bounds exception in a Try-Catch-statement. Only conditions you are not in control of (often I/O errors) should be handled at runtime. An index being out of bounds is a design error and must be fixed at design time.

I extracted the two steps from `Sub Fill_gaps` into two new methods to make the code easier to read and test.

```vb
Public Sub Fill_gaps() ' A better name would be "Decompress"
    PrintTable() 'For testing
    FillGaps()
    PrintTable() 'For testing
    AddMissingNumberOfItems()
    PrintTable() 'For testing
End Sub
```

I also added a method `PrintTable` for testing

```vb
Private Sub PrintTable()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine($"       A         B         C         D         E")
    For i = 0 To Sizes.Count - 1
        Dim A = Sizes(i)
        Dim B = If(i < Addresses.Count, Addresses(i), 0UI)
        Dim C = If(i < Indexes.Count, Indexes(i), 0UI)
        Dim D = If(i < NumberOfItems.Count, NumberOfItems(i), 0UI)
        Dim E = If(i < Description.Count, Description(i), 0UI)
        Console.WriteLine($"{A,10}{B,10}{C,10}{D,10}{E,10}")
    Next
End Sub
```

Step 1: fill the gaps (the method is self-explanatory):

```vb
Private Sub FillGaps()
    ' Fill gaps in columns C, D and E.
    ' The number of Addresses B indicates the total number of indexes.
    ' Append empty items to C, D and E until the list counts matches the
    ' expected total number of indexes.
    Dim originalIndexCount = Indexes.Count 'Save original count
    Do While Indexes.Count < Addresses.Count
        Indexes.Add(CUInt(Indexes.Count + 1)) ' Make index 1-based
        NumberOfItems.Add(1)
        Description.Add(1)
    Loop

    'Move the rows to where the index indicates.
    'We do it backwards to not overwrite existing items.
    For i As Integer = originalIndexCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim targetIndex = CInt(Indexes(i)) - 1 ' Subtract 1, indexes are 0-based

        If targetIndex <> i Then
            ' Copy to target position
            Indexes(targetIndex) = Indexes(i)
            NumberOfItems(targetIndex) = NumberOfItems(i)
            Description(targetIndex) = Description(i)

            'Clear resp. initialize old row
            Indexes(i) = CUInt(i + 1) ' Make index 1-based
            NumberOfItems(i) = 1
            Description(i) = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Step 2:

```vb
Private Sub AddMissingNumberOfItems()
    ' Insert empty rows after items with NumberOfItems > 1.
    ' We do it backwards to not mess up our indexes.
    For i As Integer = Indexes.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        For k As UInteger = 2 To NumberOfItems(i)
            Addresses.Insert(i + 1, 0)
            Indexes.Insert(i + 1, 0)
            NumberOfItems.Insert(i + 1, 0)
            Description.Insert(i + 1, 0)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If you use the following test list for the descriptions, you will better see which rows have been moved or added

```vb
Private Description As New List(Of UInt32) From {2UI, 3UI, 4UI, 5UI, 6UI, 7UI}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Olivier, for your answer. I just traced the code and I am intrigued.